# Can the behavior of the Firefox FIND be changed or augmented through an add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Can the behavior of the Firefox `FIND` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>) be changed or augmented through an add-on?

If it can not be changed, how can an add-on insert elements into the Find-bar so that it is activated at the same time as `FIND` with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>)?

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely can be changed. You can hijack and edit the find jsm module.

Here's the module:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/modules/Finder.jsm#225

I'm not sure exactly how to edit a jsm already inserted though. Maybe unload it than re import it.